# Conditional SUM in a SQL query

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT 
    CustomerCode,
    CustomerName,
    LocationCode,
    LocationName,
    ProductCode,
    ProductDesc,
    CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate) As OrderDate,
    **SUM(NoOfCube) PlantCube,**  <---- i want to set value if CubeAtPlant =1
    **SUM(NoOfCube) SiteCube,**   <---- i want to set value if CubeAtPlant =0
    ShortPlantName,
    OrderNo,
    slumpReqType,
    slumpReqFreeText,
    cubeReqType,
    cubeReqFreeText
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY OH.OrderNo ORDER BY OD.ActualStartTime ASC) AS Row,
        CustomerCode, 
        CustomerName,
        LocationCode,
        LocationName,
        OD.ProductCode,
        OD.ProductDesc,
        CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate) As OrderDate, 
        NoOfCube,
        NoOfCube SiteC,
        PLT.ShortPlantName,
        PLT.PlantCode,
        OH.OrderNo,
        slumpReqType,
            slumpReqFreeText,
            cubeReqType,
            cubeReqFreeText
    FROM 
        OrderHeader OH
        INNER JOIN OrderDetail OD ON OH.OrderNo = OD.OrderNo AND OD.DONo IS NOT NULL
        INNER JOIN EmailReportPlantList PLT ON OD.ActualBatchingPlant = PLT.PlantCode
    WHERE 1=1
        **AND NoOfCube > 0 AND CubeAtPlant = 1**----If it is then set value in PlantCube

         AND NoOfCube > 0 AND CubeAtPlant = 0   ----If it is then set value in SiteCube

    ) A
WHERE Row = 1
 
    AND (CustomerCode = '' )
    AND (PlantCode in (''))
    AND OrderDate Between '' AND ''
GROUP BY 
    CustomerCode, 
    CustomerName, 
    LocationCode,
    LocationName,
    ProductCode,
    ProductDesc, 
    CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate), 
    ShortPlantName,
    OrderNo,
    slumpReqType,
    slumpReqFreeText,
    cubeReqType,
    cubeReqFreeText
ORDER BY 
    CustomerCode, 
    CustomerName, 
    LocationCode,
    LocationName,
    ProductCode,
    ProductDesc, 
    CONVERT(DATE, OrderDate), 
    ShortPlantName,
    OrderNo
```

Kindly help me to write correct query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CASE` of `IF` to do conditional sums, if the condition is `true` add the amount to the total, if it is `false` add zero.

```
SELECT
  ...
  SUM(CASE WHEN CubeAtPlant = 1 THEN NoOfCube ELSE 0 END) AS PlantCube,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CubeAtPlant = 0 THEN NoOfCube ELSE 0 END) AS SiteCube,
  ...
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do in the `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND NoOfCube > 0 AND CubeAtPlant = 1
  AND NoOfCube > 0 AND CubeAtPlant = 0
...
```

I assume `CubeAtPlant` can only be `1` or `0`, in which case you can just have

```
WHERE 1=1
  AND NoOfCube > 0
...
```

Update your question or comment on this answer if that is not the case.

Comment: not working...kindly let me know that where need modification?

Comment: Do you have any error messages or can you explain what is "not working".
Also, if you can simplify the SQL query a bit, add sample input data and the expected output result to your question it would help me understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Manish - glad to hear you got it working.